# public IP address for the Appstream Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, cloud, aws-appstream

I would like to get a Public Ip address of the Appstream Instance . Is there any possible ways to achieve it .

Any suggestions would be really helpful .

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: i am trying to access some webservices deployed on the Appstream

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details about your implementation (like OS etc.) or requirements, simply showing the public IP of your Appstream session could be done in several ways.

The simplest could be to just add a browser (e.g. Firefox) as an app and in Appstream's Image Assistant set **Launch Parameters** to "**https://api.ipify.org**".

If you check you the [documentation](https://www.ipify.org/) for this ipify service, you can see many examples of how to get the public IP in a programmatic manner as well.